# Resultant of $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, resultants

Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer, and let $f(x) = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n(x - \alpha_k)$ be a monic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$, with the property that $f(-\alpha_k) \neq 0$ for any $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Is there anything meaningful that we can say about $\operatorname{Res}(f(x), f(-x))$, the resultant of $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$?

To rephrase, what can be said about the value of the product $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^nf(-\alpha_k)$? Perhaps, it can be expressed somehow through $n$ and the discriminant of $f(x)$?

One thing that I can note is that $f(-\alpha_1), \ldots, f(-\alpha_k)$ are algebraic conjugates, which means that their product is equal to the norm of $f(-\alpha_1)$. Thus, up to a sign, the product $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^nf(-\alpha_k)$ is equal to the constant coefficient of the minimal polynomial of $f(-\alpha_1)$. But what is this constant coefficient is a mystery.

Comment: Just $n$ and the discriminant of $f$ are definitely not enough to determine the resultant you want - there will be polynomials of same degree and same discriminant but different resultants.

Comment: @Wojowu, I see, that makes sense.

Comment: Up to sign it's $\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n (\alpha_i + \alpha_j)$.

Comment: @WillSawin thanks, but I am trying to avoid expressing this quantity through its roots, and use things like discriminant / degree / constant coefficient of f(x) instead. Perhaps, this is impossible, or maybe it is possible with the specific case which I am dealing with, where the Galois group of f(x) is Abelian.

Comment: It's obviously a symmetric function in the roots of $f(x)$ (explicitly described in Will's answer), so it's a polynomial in the coefficients of $f(x)$. Have you tried writing it out for $n=2,3,4$, say, and seeing what that polynomial looks like. For $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$, I get $4a^2b$, which doesn't seem related to much of anything.

Comment: Thank you, @JoeSilverman. Looks like I got my answer: this may not be the right question to ask and I need to look closely at the properties of polynomials that I am working with instead. Curious fact though: if $f(x) = x^n + \cdots + a_{n - 1}x + a_n$, then it looks like $\operatorname{Res}(f(x), f(-x)) = 2^na_nb_n^2$ for some integer $b_n$.

Comment: @Anton That follows from the product formula 
$\prod_{i,j=1}^n (\alpha_i + \alpha_j)$.  
The $i=j$ factors give $2^n \prod_i \alpha_i = (-2)^n a_n$,
and each of the $i\neq j$ factors appears twice.
(Their product, which you call $b_n$, is $\pm$ the resultant w.r.t. $\beta$ of the
linear and constant coefficients of the remainder of $f(x) \bmod x^2-\beta$.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, thanks! I think your observation regarding the connection between $b_n$ and the remainder of $f(x)$ mod $x^2 - \beta$ is actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have $\mathrm{Res}(f(x),f(-x))=2^n a_n P(\alpha)^2$, where
$P(\alpha)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(\alpha_i+\alpha_j)$. By
e.g. the case $d=2$ of Exercise 7.30 in *Enumerative Combinatorics*,
vol. 2, we have $P(\alpha)=s_{n-1,n-2,\dots,1}(\alpha)$, where
$s_{n-1,n-2,\dots,1}$ is a Schur function. By the dual Jacobi-Trudi
identity (Corollary 7.16.2 of the above reference), we get
$$ \mathrm{Res}(f(x),f(-x)) = 2^n a_n
 \left( \det[a_{n-2i+j}]_{i,j=1}^{n-1}\right)^2, $$
where we set $a_0=1$ and $a_{-k}=0$ for $k>0$. For instance, when
$n=3$ the determinant is
$$ \left| \begin{array}{cc} a_2 & a_3\\ 1 & a_1\end{array} \right|
      =a_2a_1-a_3. $$

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion [above](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382552).

Also, if $f(x) = x^n + \dotsb + a_{n-1}x + a_n$, then

- for $n = 2$, $\operatorname{Res}(f(x), f(-x)) = 2^2a_2a_1^2$
- for $n = 3$, $\operatorname{Res}(f(x), f(-x)) = 2^3a_3(a_3 - a_1a_2)^2$
- for $n = 4$, $\operatorname{Res}(f(x), f(-x)) = 2^4a_4(a_4a_1^2 - a_1a_2a_3 + a_3^2)^2$.

Comment: I edited in a link to @RichardStanley's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382552), which I assume is what you meant by "above".

Comment: @LSpice Since Richard Stanley’s answer was posted 11 hours after Anton’s, that’s clearly impossible. The “discussion above” must have referred to the comment thread under the question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, [agreed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382504/resultant-of-fx-and-f-x/382511#comment972689_382511), thanks; I didn't notice the time stamps.  Hopefully @‍Anton will edit in the appropriate links themselves (I am reluctant to guess again).  Reminder about how to [link to comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763/is-linking-to-comments-possible). ‍